# Memory problems with turning a large Xarray to a DataFrame, Python

Tags: dataframe, ram, python-xarray

I have an x,y,time xarray of about 2 million datapoints. I have tried turning it into a dask DataArray and then turning that into a dataframe, but there isn't enough memory. I use colab. Is there a different way to do this that might fit into colabs memory?

```
dask_array = da.array.from_array(xarray.values, chunks= 
(xarray.shape[0], 100, 100))

#reshape and transpose to make rows of timeseries for each 
point
dask_t = 
dask_array.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(arr.shape[1]*arr.shape[2], 
                                          arr.shape[0])

#prepare column names for timeseries
feat_cols = ['time_'+str(i) for i in 
range(dask_array.shape[0])]


#turn into a dataframe


pd.DataFrame(dask_t.compute(), columns=feat_cols)
```

Comment: By my count the size of the array alone would be about `2e6*100*100*8/(1024^3)=149 GB`. Does your computer have several times that amount of memory? If not, what's the question?

Comment: In other words - it doesn't really surprise me that this causes a memory error. Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?